# How to show contents of List<string> in ComboBox using Caliburn.micro?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, caliburn.micro

I'm having trouble simply showing the contents of my List in the ComboBox using Caliburn.micros BindableCollection. I get three blank options, but when I chose one of them I get the correct value back so I know it's working. Obviously I would also like to see what it is I'm choosing.

I've tried creating a local string and having it = myList[i] in a for loop. I've even created a random string and tried binding it to my TextBlock using the same naming convention, but I just can't get it to work. I won't add that here since it doesn't work. Hopefully one of you can nudge me in the right direction. I'm new to Caliburn, MVVM, binding, etc....

```
    public List<string> languages = new List<string> {"ENGLISH", "SPANISH", "CHINESE"};

    public BindableCollection<string> Language { get; set; }

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        Language = new BindableCollection<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < languages.Count; i++)
        {
            Language.Add(languages[i]);
        }
    }
```

//XAML Code\

```
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Language}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LanguageOptions}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LanguageOptions}" />
```

The property `Language` is  `BindableCollection` of `string`. It doesn't have a sub-property called `LanguageOptions`.

You could instead use the following

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Language}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Or to make it even more simpler, you could avoid the ItemTemplate. For example,

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Language}"/>
```

That would help you fix the Combo Box.

Comment: Hello Anu. Thank you for your help. Both of your examples worked. The reason I have itemTemplate is because I was following a tutorial and that's how they were doing it. I have a question for you though. Why does Text = "{Binding}" work. Aren't I supposed to tell it what property to bind to instead of leaving it blank?

Comment: @luigi In the case of "{Binding}", the control(TextBlock) would inherit the DataContext from the parent element, which in this case is the ComboBox

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your help it is greatly appreciated